# Multiple keyboard shortcuts for action in Qt Designer

Tags: qt4, keyboard-shortcuts, designer

I'm having a weird problem with Qt designer. I have the following shortcut for a refresh action: <kbd>F5</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

The idea is that on Macintosh, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> maps to <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> which is more intuitive and on Windows, <kbd>F5</kbd> does the job.

The problem is that only the first shortcut seems to be active. Is there a way for me to change the action's shortcut so that we have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> active on Mac and <kbd>F5</kbd> everywhere else? I know I can do this in code but I'd rather do it in designer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in few ways. At first, you can use [QKeySequence](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qkeysequence.html) and assign `QKeySequence::Refresh` as a shortcut. Another way is creating `QList` with 2 `QKeySequence` elements created with [Qt::Key enum](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qt.html#Key-enum): `Qt::Key_F5` and `Qt::Key_Control` + `Qt::Key_R` (on Mac OS X <kbd>Command</kbd> buttton will be assigned, on others <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>). This list is then passed to [QActionsetShortcuts()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qaction.html#setShortcuts). After this, on Max OS X <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> will trigger refresh action, and on other systems <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Finally if you want to set <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> without <kbd>F5</kbd> on Mac OS X and <kbd>F5</kbd> without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on others, you should do conditional compilation, i.e.:

```
#ifdef Q_WS_MAC
//set Qt::Key_Control + Qt::Key_R
#else
//set Qt::Key_F5
```

more on OS defines you'll find [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtglobal.html)

Comment: I know how to do it in code, my question was about how to do it in Designer :)

Comment: @cheez in designer in action editor, you have to click action then in shortcut field press keys. On Mac OS X Ctrl will be changed into Command by qt, without any additional work.

Comment: Is there a way for me to change the action's shortcut so that we have Ctrl + R active on Mac and F5 everywhere else? I know I can do this in code but I'd rather do it in designer.

Comment: I don't know about possibility of setting something dependent on OS in Designer. Probably there isn't such ability, because (as you can see in my answer) detecting OS is rather matter of compilation (defines), so you'll have to code your shortcuts.